# Find the current filepath of a renamed/moved file from looking at a previous revision

Tags: git, bash

If I'm exploring a project's history, sometimes I am viewing a file at a commit that is on a different path than it currently is in the current working directory.

Basically, if I have a commit id, and a file's old path at that commit id, is there any git command or bash script that I can use to figure out that file's current path, after being renamed/moved in the current working directory? I was thinking something like a `git log --follow`, but in reverse, and not taking too long to run.

I want to be able to use this method in combination with vim-fugitive, so a well-performing solution (given git structure capabilities) would be a nice plus.

Any bright ideas out there?

Comment: Hey there, that's great to add little entertainment in your question, but please focus on the actual message. My English is surelly not that good, but it's really hard to understand what you are asking here and moreover we have to deal with kind of jokes.. Really not helping

Comment: Thanks, these kinds of things still slip my mind every once in a while!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to avoid a rant here. :-)

What you want is `git log --follow --reverse`, to which you supply the *old* path name, and perhaps a revision range: `git log --follow stop^..start path`.

Alas, this doesn't actually work.

The problem is that `git log --follow` is implemented using a horrible hack.  The `git log` code works as usual, doing history simplification and looking for commits whose diff or combined diff against its parent(s) shows a modification to the named *`path`*.  If the *type* of the modification is a rename—note that `--follow` implies `--find-renames`—the `git log` code notes this, and upon moving to the parent commit, *changes the name it's looking for*.  Now instead of looking for `new/path/to/file.ext`, it is looking for `old/different/name`, for instance.

This only works when you know the final name, since it only changes names in the "step back" direction.  It seems like it should work fine to invert the sense of the diff-name-change, finding the modification and changing names to the *new* name in the "step forward" direction, but in fact, `--reverse` doesn't step forward at all.  It's still doing the analysis "backwards": it just reverses the *output* of `git log`, after the commits have been found.

Fundamentally, Git *must* work backwards, as commits know their parents but don't know their children.  Still, it *should* have a "slow mode" where it can generate the list, then walk it in reverse, parent-to-child instead of child-to-parent.  Adding this to `git log --follow` turns out to be nontrivial, though (I took a stab at doing it trivially some years ago, and failed).  If you are willing to throw a lot of memory and at least one additional process at the problem, you can run `git log --find-renames --topo-order --name-status` (perhaps with `-m` as well) and post-process the rename list.

Comment: That's a lot of very helpful information. There could be a solution in there, but I have to play around a bit more before I'm sure.

Comment: @alias65536: the entirely-rant-free version is that Git can't do this in one step, even though it should be able to. I have had the desire to do this before and have (in the past, when Git was more primitive) used `git whatchanged` and a lot of output searching. Note that `git whatchanged` still exists but is deprecated; you're supposed to use `git log` as suggested above instead.

Comment: Wish I could give 1/2 point acceptance to both your answers. I think I'm going to do post processing on `git log --reverse --format="%H" --name-status --diff-filter=R <old-browsing-sha>..` to get the new filepath I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can show all file actions using `git log --name-status` with `--diff-filter` - this shows all file events, along with a letter that shows what kind of modification occurred. you want to filter `R` (rename) and/or `C` (change) events:

```
git log --name-status --oneline --diff-filter=RC
```

From the man pages:

> --diff-filter=[(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)...[*]]
>
> Select only files that are Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D), Modified (M),
>          Renamed (R), have their type (i.e. regular file, symlink, submodule, ...) changed
>          (T), are Unmerged (U), are Unknown (X), or have had their pairing Broken (B).